# How to show that countable union of $F_\sigma$ is $F_\sigma$

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing

On https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/countable-intersection-of-f-sigma-sets.666055/

Is it claimed that it is obvious that countable union of $F_\sigma$ is $F_\sigma$

Can someone elaborate why this is the case? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We want to prove that 
$$\bigcup_{i\in \mathbb{N}} \bigcup_{j\in \mathbb{N}} U_{i,\,j}$$
with $U_{i,\,j}$ closed, is actually a countable union of closed sets. Now rewrite as $$\bigcup_{(i,j) \in \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}} U_{i,\,j}$$
So if the set $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ is countable, we are done. This is true, do you know this result? A proof can be found here: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cartesian_Product_of_Countable_Sets_is_Countable

Comment: The $U_{i,j}$ should be closed, not open.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a matter of cardinalities. A countable union of countable unions of closed sets is still a countable union of closed sets.